# UIButton touch is not respoding in xcode 4.5 in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios5, ios6, uibutton

I have created a project in xcode 4.3 with development target 5.1. Now i want to update my app for iphone 5. I have just run the code in xcode 4.5, It compiled and run successfully but some of the buttons on top and bottom of the screen are not responding any touch event.

Comment: More detail necessary.

Comment: The level of detail that you provided is not nearly enough for an educated guess on your question, let alone answering it definitively.

Comment: Do you really think anybody can answer your question based on such little information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know the issue but removed older UIButtons and added new buttons worked for me.